# How do I have the meta description/keywords in 2 languages for different pages?

Tags: joomla, localization

I'm working on a site in Joomla and I've got it in two languages, French and English. Is it possible to have the meta description and keywords in French on the French pages and English on the English ones? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Note: My joomla version is 3.6.5. I guess it should be same if you use 3.x.

Go to Extensions > Language(s) > Content Languages

Click the language you want to change the meta tags.

Go to the "Metadata" tab.

You will find "Meta Keywords" and "Meta Description"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an extension such as [Joom!Fish](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/multi-lingual-content/460) to manage your translations? I believe you can control pretty much all aspects of a Joomla site with this component.

Also on the Joomla wiki is this (unfinished) page on [adding multi-language support](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_multi-language_support) to a Joomla site.

Comment: Yea JoomFish... but i'm not sure how to do it